# Always-on-Internet licence verification library for Windows desktop clients

Tags: windows, windows-7, .net, desktop-client

[Diablo 3 requires user to maintain a constant Internet connection](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/358901/diablo-3-always-on-internet-requirement-is-more-than-copy-protection/), and I really do think that this is an effective way to deter piracy. From what I understand Diablo 3 writes their own software protection component.

Is there an off-the-shelf software+online server component that I can buy, so that I can integrate it into my software?  My software shall run on Windows 7 and above, using .Net 4.5.

Comment: My two cents here: that kind of protection is a real P.I.T.A. for users.